# Data is not being inserted when trigger fired

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have following trigger fired successfully on table before insert but data is not being inserted into table after trigger is fired

```
CREATE TRIGGER `limit_refferals` BEFORE INSERT ON `wpmr_aff_referrals`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 DECLARE vCNT INT;
 DECLARE USERID varchar(50);
 DECLARE AFFILIATEID varchar(50) default NEW.affiliate_id;
  DECLARE USER_AFFID varchar(50);
DECLARE i INTEGER;
     DECLARE curs1 CURSOR FOR 
     SELECT  USER_ID,affiliate_id
 FROM `wpmr_aff_referrals` WHERE affiliate_id=AFFILIATEID;


 SELECT CUSTOMERLEVEL(AFFILIATEID) INTO vCNT;

IF (vCNT >=3) THEN  
while (AFFILIATEID is not null) do
OPEN curs1;    
    read_loop : LOOP    
    FETCH curs1 INTO USERID,AFFILIATEID;
    SELECT CUSTOMERLEVEL(AFFILIATEID) INTO vCNT;
SELECT affiliate_id INTO USER_AFFID FROM wpmr_aff_affiliates_users WHERE USER_ID=USERID;


    IF (vCNT>=3) THEN 

    set AFFILIATEID=USER_AFFID;
ELSE

set new.affiliate_id := USER_AFFID;
set AFFILIATEID=null;
    END IF;    

    END LOOP read_loop;
    CLOSE curs1;
   END WHILE; 

 END IF;

END
```

Comment: Are you saying no data is inserted into `wpmr_aff_referrals` on an insert or that data is being inserted but affiliate_id is not as expected?

Comment: @P.salman yes in the said table data not being inserted